# Mercury - How do I set an option element's 'selected' property?

Tags: javascript, virtual-dom, mercuryjs

How do I set the [selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) property of an `option` element with [Mercury](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury)/[virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom)?

I've tried the following, but no `selected` property appears on the `<option>`:

```
h('select', {
  name: 'selectedRole', 
}, [
  h('option', {value: 'user', selected: true}, 'User'),
])
```

Instead, it results in this:

```
<select name="selectedRole">
  <option value="user">User</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hrm... this is tricky. The `mercury` tag is for the language Mercury, not the framework. Maybe need a new tag `mercury-framework`?

Comment: @zxq9 Thanks. I created tag 'mercuryjs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, it appears this is how it works with Mercury. When you set `selected` to `true` on an `option`, it does become selected even though the property isn't visible on the HTML element.

However, I can only make it work in a small demo, not in my full application. Thus, there could be a bug in virtual-dom.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("option[value='user']").attr('selected', true);
```

I have also had this problem with the html5 datalist tag's list attribute. 
One work-around is to use javascript, or jquery, to dynamically assign this attribute.